# Nginx & long poll: Best practices to reduce memory and bandwidth footprint

Tags: nginx, best-practices, instant-messaging, long-polling

I use nginx in this mode for [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html) and chat clients along with gzip.

```
location ~* /http-bind/ {       
     proxy_buffering off;
     keepalive_timeout 55;
     access_log off;
     tcp_nodelay on;
     proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:1111;
}
```

Is this the best approach to **managing long polling** in nginx.

I also use just one worker process for altogether for web & chat (single CPU). Is that fine?

Answer (score 1):

From [nginx.org](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_buffering), "For Comet applications based on long-polling it is important to set proxy_buffering to off, otherwise the asynchronous response is buffered and the Comet does not work.".

```
proxy_buffering off;
```

You might want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160454/nginx-proxy-to-comet) thread too.